# Getting result of spark submit job in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

We have a standalone Spark cluster running on several machines, and currently we run Spark jobs in client mode meaning that the driver program is getting executed on the host machine not on the cluster.

We want to be able to run the driver program on the cluster and submit our jobs to the Spark cluster. Using the `spark-submit` bash script provided by Spark itself, we can give it a python module and Spark cluster runs it on the cluster. But what I want now is to get the result of that parallel computation back in python because I want to write the results to a PostgreSQL database for further use.

How can get the results of a Spark job deployed using cluster mode back in python? How can I submit a python module using pyspark in python not using the `spark-submit` bash script.

Comment: just write data to Postgres from Spark job itself, using JDBC

Comment: I just want to use spark for the actual computation. I don't want to be coupled to my database. Suppose in the future I want to calculate some value using parallel processing and then write it into some database and redis and maybe create an event in kafka. I don't want to send all the libraries needed to do all these things into the cluster for each job.